# Why does the FadeIn/Out function not work when moving from JQuery 2.2.4 to 3.6.0

Tags: jquery, version

I have a loader that is shown until the page is done loading that then fades out while the page fades in. I put the code in the head of my website. I decided to move from JQuery 2.2.4 to 3.6.0 and now it's not working. What was changed between these two versions? 
Here's the code:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");;
    $("#page").fadeIn("slow");;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That use of `.load()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 3.0.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)